# Как получть данные из отношения по условию?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы, апи роли и апи пермисии.

Cтруктура такая id, name

Они связаны много ко многим

Нужно получить все апи роли где присутствует персисия с определенным индексом, но если роль содержит такую пермиссию, то получить нужно эту роль, со всем ее пермиссиями.

Я пробовал например вот так, но возвращается конкретно одна строчка с этой пермиссией, а мне нужно что бы вернулась роль со всеми ее пермиссиями если она содержит пермиссию с id 390. Пробовал разными запросами и с вложенным, возвращается все ровно не все принадлежащие строчки из пермиссий

```
SELECT * FROM public.dict_api_roles dar
left join link_api_roles_permissions larp on larp."dictApiRolesId" = dar.id 
left join dict_api_permissions dap on dap.id = larp."dictApiPermissionsId"
where dap.id = 390

select * from public.dict_api_roles dar
left join link_api_roles_permissions larp on 
larp."dictApiRolesId" = dar.id 
left join dict_api_permissions dap on dap.id = 
larp."dictApiPermissionsId"
where dar.id in(
SELECT dar.id FROM public.dict_api_roles
where dap.id = 390
)
```

Comment: как ни крути, сначала надо получить список ролей, которые содержат искомые разрешения (от пермиссий ваших чуть глаза не вытекли). То есть берете таблицу связи, в ней фильтрацию по разрешениям, потом результат джойните ко всему остальному по полученным ид ролей. Хотя если список не большой, то проще через IN и подзарпрос вернуть роли.

Comment: Нифига не понятно из вопроса какие данные, как связаны и какой результат нужен, сделайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: джоинете все таблицы которые нужны на выдаче, а в where пишите `where dar.id in(select dictApiRolesId from link_api_roles_permissions where dictApiPermissionsId = 390)`

Answer (score 0):

```
with matched_roles as (
 SELECT larp."dictApiRolesId" as roleId 
 FROM link_api_roles_permissions larp 
 where larp."dictApiPermissionsId" = 390
)
select * 
 from public.dict_api_roles dar
 left join link_api_roles_permissions larp on larp."dictApiRolesId" = dar.id 
 left join dict_api_permissions dap on dap.id = larp."dictApiPermissionsId"
 where dar.id in( SELECT roleId from matched_roles)
```